# How do you use find_previous() in a select query in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the span (lets call it AAA before a specific span - BBB. This BBB span only shows up certain times on the page and I only want the AAA's which directly precede the BBBs.

Is there a way to select AAA's that are only proceeded by BBB? Or, to get to my proposed question, how can you use find_previous when you're running a select query? I am successful if I just use select_one -

```
AAA= selsoup.select_one('span.BBB').find_previous().text
```

but when I try to use select to pull all entries I get an error message (You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element.)

I've tried applying .find_previous in a for loop but that doesnt work either. Any suggestions?

Sorry, I probably should have added this before:

Adding code from the page -

```
<tr class="tree">
                                <th class="AAA"><a href="../../../access/floor/" title="jko">What I want right here<span class="BBB">(Aba: The New Look)</span></a></th>
```

Comment: Please post an HTML snippet as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.find_previous()` you can use `+` in your CSS selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span class="ccc"">txt</span>
<span class="aaa"">This I don't Want</span>

<span class="bbb"">txt</span>
<span class="aaa"">* This I Want *</span>

<span class="ccc"">txt</span>
<span class="aaa"">This I don't Want</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for aaa in soup.select(".bbb + .aaa"):
    print(aaa.text)
```

Prints:

```
* This I Want *
```

---

EDIT: Based on your edit:

```
bbb = soup.select_one(".AAA .BBB")
print(bbb.text)
```

Prints:

```
(Aba: The New Look)
```

Comment: This looks great but I really should have included the code as this looks to be more complicated than I thought. Thank you so much for this - I still learned something. Much appreciated. I will keep trying to see how this solution can work but right now it doesnt quite do it (because I don't know what I'm doing - solution looks great).

Comment: @jmarlow989 I edited my answer. You can use CSS selector `.AAA .BBB` to select `class="BBB"` tags that are inside tags with `class="AAA"`.